# Why jwt token shows payload even i didn't provide secret (Signature ) in Jwt.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjIsImlhdCI6MTU2ODY1NjI1OX0.E2TNtWjqyPC-4myEom6leLJgE96ZlQOq0-mcBr3p5QU`

If we place the token which is generated from my code using JsonWebToken in Jwt.io site it is decoded immediately even though I did not provide the secret to validate.
I don't know why it shows. Can somebody explain the reason for that?

--Then what is purpose of SECRET in Jwt??

Comment: see where it says "invalid signature" ... now type in **your** secret, then paste your token, and voila, valid

Comment: but finally we need to get data in payload right?? then what if not provide Signature

Comment: what? the data isn't encrypted because the client may need to read it ... but the client can't ALTER it when sending it back to the server, because the server, which knows the secret, should validate it - in other words, validation for JWT is only done on the server, to make sure the client isn't altering the token

Comment: ohhh! thank you for quick response Got It!!

Comment: I think you might need to take a look at a jwt explanation online

Comment: For suppose if we place any valid info like passwords in token it goes outside

Answer (score 8):

I think you're getting a little confused between encryption and signing.

A JSON web token is not encryped, it's just base64 encoded meaning it's very simple to decode and view by anyone.

It is however signed, which means it has a `hash` generated based on all the information within it and a secret key. Only those with a secret key (for symmetric hashing) or the public key (for asymmetric hashing) are able to confirm that the token has been hashed correctly, and only the provider of the key (who owns the secret token) is able to create valid hashes.

What this does, is gives you confidence that the token has been created by the person/service you think it was created from, preventing impersonation etc and therefore allows you to trust the `claims` that have been made within the token. If that hash were invalid for any reason you would immediately reject the token on the basis it's most likely forged.

Note that as @FlorentMorselli mentioned there is such a think as an encrypted token called a [JWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Encryption).

Comment: Vote up, but it should be mentioned that JWT can be encrypted. JWS aren't encrypted but JWE are (see RFC 7516).

Comment: @FlorentMorselli thanks for sharing that - I wasn't aware of JWE's!